Converting Python Script to .exe and Handling Complex Spatial Dependencies
I'm trying to convert the following Python script to an executable (.exe) file
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance, ImageTk, ImageOps
import numpy as np
import cv2
import rasterio
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
class ImageProcessor:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Traitement d'Image")

        # Interface utilisateur
        self.image_label = tk.Label(root)
        self.image_label.pack()

        self.load_button = tk.Button(root, text="Charger Image", command=self.load_image)
        self.load_button.pack()

        self.process_button = tk.Button(root, text="Ajuster Luminosité", command=self.process_image, state=tk.DISABLED)
        self.process_button.pack()

        self.color_button = tk.Button(root, text="Filtrage des Couleurs", command=self.apply_color_filter, state=tk.DISABLED)
        self.color_button.pack()

        self.detect_button = tk.Button(root, text="Détection d'Oliviers", command=self.detect_blue_areas, state=tk.DISABLED)
        self.detect_button.pack()

        self.save_button = tk.Button(root, text="Exporter SHP", command=self.save_shapefile, state=tk.DISABLED)
        self.save_button.pack()

        self.centroid_button = tk.Button(root, text="Comptage", command=self.create_and_display_centroids, state=tk.DISABLED)
        self.centroid_button.pack()

        self.centroid_count_label = tk.Label(root, text="Points Centraux : 0", fg="blue")
        self.centroid_count_label.pack()

        self.projection_label = tk.Label(root, text="Projection : Non détectée", fg="blue")
        self.projection_label.pack()

        # Initialisation des variables
        self.image_path = None
        self.image = None
        self.contours = None

    def load_image(self):
        """Charger une image."""
        try:
            self.image_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(
                title="Charger une Image", 
                filetypes=[("Fichiers d'Image", "*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png;*.tif;*.tiff;*.geotiff")]
            )
            if self.image_path:
                self.image = Image.open(self.image_path)
                self.show_image()
                self.process_button.config(state=tk.NORMAL)
                self.color_button.config(state=tk.NORMAL)
                self.detect_button.config(state=tk.NORMAL)
                self.save_button.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
                self.centroid_button.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
                self.centroid_count_label.config(text="Points Centraux : 0")
                # Détecter les informations de projection si nécessaire
                self.detect_projection()
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Erreur lors du chargement de l'image : {e}")

    def show_image(self):
        """Afficher l'image dans l'interface.""" 
        self.tk_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)
        self.image_label.config(image=self.tk_image)
        self.image_label.image = self.tk_image

    def process_image(self):
        """Ajuster la luminosité de l'image.""" 
        if self.image:
            enhancer = ImageEnhance.Brightness(self.image)
            enhanced_image = enhancer.enhance(1.5)
            self.image = enhanced_image
            self.show_image()

    def apply_color_filter(self):
        """Appliquer un filtre de couleur à l'image.""" 
        if self.image:
            color_adjusted_image = ImageOps.colorize(self.image.convert("L"), black="blue", white="yellow")
            self.image = color_adjusted_image
            self.show_image()

    def detect_blue_areas(self):
        """Détecter les zones bleues dans l'image et afficher les contours.""" 
        if self.image:
            # Convertir l'image Pillow en format OpenCV
            image_cv = np.array(self.image)
            if image_cv.ndim == 3:  # Vérifier si c'est une image couleur
                image_cv = cv2.cvtColor(image_cv, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

            # Convertir en espace de couleur HSV pour détecter le bleu
            hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image_cv, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
            # Définir la plage de couleurs bleues en HSV
            lower_blue = np.array([100, 50, 50])
            upper_blue = np.array([140, 255, 255])
            # Appliquer un masque pour obtenir seulement les pixels bleus
            mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_blue, upper_blue)

            # Détecter les contours sur le masque
            self.contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

            # Dessiner les contours sur l'image originale pour la visualisation
            cv2.drawContours(image_cv, self.contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)  # Contours verts

            # Convertir à nouveau en image Pillow pour l'affichage
            self.image = Image.fromarray(cv2.cvtColor(image_cv, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
            self.show_image()
            self.save_button.config(state=tk.NORMAL)
            self.centroid_button.config(state=tk.NORMAL)

    def create_and_display_centroids(self):
        """Créer et afficher les points centraux pour chaque polygone.""" 
        if self.contours:
            centroids = []
            for contour in self.contours:
                if contour.shape[0] >= 3:  # S'assurer que le contour a suffisamment de points pour former un polygone
                    polygon = Polygon(contour[:, 0, :])
                    centroid = polygon.centroid
                    centroids.append(centroid)
            
            # Créer un GeoDataFrame pour les centroïdes
            centroids_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=centroids)

            # Mettre à jour le label de comptage des centroïdes
            self.centroid_count_label.config(text=f"Points Centraux : {len(centroids)}")

            # Dessiner les centroïdes sur l'image
            self.draw_centroids(centroids)

    def draw_centroids(self, centroids):
        """Dessiner les centroïdes sur l'image."""
        if self.image:
            # Convertir l'image en tableau numpy pour traitement
            image_cv = np.array(self.image)
            if image_cv.ndim == 3:
                image_cv = cv2.cvtColor(image_cv, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

            # Dessiner un cercle pour chaque centroïde
            for centroid in centroids:
                cv2.circle(image_cv, (int(centroid.x), int(centroid.y)), 5, (255, 0, 0), -1)  # Cercle rouge

            # Convertir à nouveau en image Pillow pour l'affichage
            self.image = Image.fromarray(cv2.cvtColor(image_cv, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
            self.show_image()

    def save_shapefile(self):
        """Exporter les contours en fichier SHP.""" 
        if self.contours:
            # Créer un GeoDataFrame avec les contours détectés
            polygons = [Polygon(contour[:, 0, :]) for contour in self.contours]
            gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=polygons)

            # Demander à l'utilisateur où sauvegarder le fichier SHP
            save_path = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=".shp", filetypes=[("Shapefile", "*.shp")])
            if save_path:
                gdf.to_file(save_path)
                print(f"Fichier SHP sauvegardé à : {save_path}")

    def detect_projection(self):
        """Détecter la projection de l'image si possible.""" 
        if self.image_path.endswith('.tif') or self.image_path.endswith('.geotiff'):
            with rasterio.open(self.image_path) as src:
                crs = src.crs
                self.projection_label.config(text=f"Projection : {crs}")
        else:
            self.projection_label.config(text="Projection : Non détectée")

# Lancer l'application
root = tk.Tk()
app = ImageProcessor(root)
root.mainloop()

The script involves complex spatial dependencies and uses libraries such as GDAL, Fiona, Shapely, and Rasterio. I’ve run into compatibility issues when trying to bundle everything together.
Can you guide me through an approach for this?
I’ve considered using PyInstaller, but I’m open to other suggestions. It would be great if you could test the process on your system to ensure it works before sharing the solution.
